# Wear app only work on debug

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, android-debug, android-wear-data-api

I'm developing a application to wearable devices, and I had all working perfectly while i'm in debug mode using Android Studio and Wear emulator and also a real Wear device.

I can comunicate Wear->Handheld and Handheld->Wear, send data, messages and all, i can package the two apk's in one and both apk's gets installed on each device.

The problem is that only works while debuging, if I stop debuging and open the app on Wear the app seems to start but it remains thinking and 1 minute later appears the clock screen and all went to normal.

I think that it has to be something about the comunication about wear->handheld, but i don't understand how can work on debugg and not on release.

Someone had those kind of problems or know the differences about debug and release regarding the comunication between devices?

Comment: If you find somthing useful, Please share with us

Comment: use 1 keystore for both apps (wear and hand)